# Excel, IF Greater than function, time and date

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns of times,

Column A has date and time, Column B has just time. 
I want to know how I can view when these times of column A surpass the times of column B.

The issue may be that column A has the date and time, or the issue could be that there is no date offset as to know which is higher then the other?

I have tried the basic `IF(a2>b2,"yes","no")` which gives inaccurate results.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(A2-INT(A2)>B2,"yes","no")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

This works because the date part of the number is the Integer, while the time is the decimal.  So we want to compare the decimals not the integers.

By removing the integer part we now can correctly deduce whether the time is greater or less than the criteria.

Comment: `MOD(A2, 1)>B2` is another valid comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped - I just started understanding doing `A2 - Int(A2)` (part is an int. and the other decimal?), and then you confuse me even more with `mod()`!  There's a lot of stuff going on in those simple ideas, nice job guys!

Comment: @Jeeped Huh, never would have thought about MOD(), but mathematically it makes sense and is less typing.  I like less typing.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Looks good, lets say the dates  range from 1st to 2nd, Now lets say the time is 9 Pm on the first in Col A on the 1st, and Col B is 12:30 am on the 2nd(even though it doesnt say), I have a column C containing the day offset(either 0 or 1). How can I include your above solution but add it so it takes into account the day? As 9 PM should be no as it is before 12:30 on the next day.

Comment: @Ladiesman191 - I would  suggest you [close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this question and start another with the updated information lest this become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625).

Comment: @Ladiesman191 that is not the question you asked here.  It is usually frowned upon to modify the question after receiving an answer that answers the question asked.  It should be another question, with proper data and expected outcomes

Comment: if I may elaborate, so 0 in column C would be 1st, and 1 would be the 2nd.  ex: 14:00 on 0 is 2 pm on the 1st & 2:00 with 1 on column C, is 2 am on the 2nd.